# автоформатирование foreach в IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, foreach

При автоматическом создании цикла 'foreach' IDEA создает его в таком виде:

```
for (double a :
        array) {
    //do something
}
```

Где и как изменить настройки, чтобы IDEA автоматически писала условие цикла на одной строке?

```
for (double a : array) {
    //do somethinfg
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто используй шаблон `iter` вместо `foreach`.

Помимо данного есть еще много различных шаблонов. Больше узнать можно в [документации к IDEA раздел Live Templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/live-templates.html)